# How hot is too hot for a transformer?

Tags: transformer

I recently ordered a custom transformer and under load with half of its rated current it heats up to 55 °C, and now it's started to radiate a "weez" noise.

Is this normal? How hot is too hot for a transformer?

How can I get rid of the noise? Pushing it down doesn't help!

**Update:** the iron core was loose (or wasn't tight enough), I returned the transformer to be fixed with a new core.

Comment: What does this transformer do?  Is it for a switch mode power supply?  What frequency does it operate at?

Comment: 55 deg is not that much, but it depends to the insulation class. Weezing noise is due to loose tight of lamination. Both phenomena together may also indicate a low quality product.

Comment: The key here is what is the winding or core temperature.  Also, what is the core material.  Was any kind of thermal analysis done of this transformer?  I agree that 55 deg C is not that hot, assuming a room temperature environment.  The core/windings are probably 15 deg C or more hotter, so that would mean 70 deg C.  If this thing is supposed to work in a 85 deg C environment, that wold push those internal temperatures up to 130 deg C, way too hot for reliable operation.  Like I said earlier, we need more information.

Comment: @SteveSh It's a step down transformer working with 220V at 50Hz. for a linear regulator. the core is iron.

Comment: To reduce noise, place in a bowl of varnish/conformal coating, place that in a vacuum chamber, pull vacuum for an hour, let air in slowly, remove xfmr, bake/cure dry. Note this may slightly worsen temperature issues, as the center will now be more physically insulated.

Comment: @rdtsc That should be already done in the workshop, so it explains my comment on probably low quality built.

Comment: And does it make a difference if they're in disguise?

Comment: The transformer's nameplate should state service current limits. If it doesn't have a nameplate it's not a real transformer, it's mystery meat.

Comment: +1 for updating to tell us what the deal was.  I am, like many people on here, always curious about "how the story ended".

Comment: If the magic smoke gets out, it was too hot.

Comment: *How* did you measure the temperature? *Where* was the temperature measured?

Comment: Thank you for your vote. When you get a new one, ask the shop about the insulation class. Nominal flux density - it should be max 1.6T, but you would get even 1.9T on Ali, eBay, they are smaller and cheaper, but they heat even without load, they blow fuses, they produce higher harmonics,...Then as @rdtsc said, it shall be impregnated in vacuum and cured. This is where I order: http://tik-transformatorji.si/izdelek5.php , you can compare the weight (kg) Skupaj - means total weight VS. yours, to see if they were cheating on flux density.

Comment: And don't forget that as rule of thumb RMS current in the windings is roughly 1.8 times the average DC output of a full wave capacitive input rectifier. This is over three times the copper losses and temperature rise if this is your case

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The maximum allowed winding temperature VS. insulation class:

[image]

Comment: Except in a quick catastrophic failure, you can usually smell transformer insulation overheating before any permanent damage is done. It's hard to describe smells, but it's a bit like what you would get if you were cooking something which had "gone horribly wrong" for some reason.

Comment: @alephzero I'm not that good at cooking, but even when it goes "horribly wrong" for me it doesn't smell as bad as fried insulation ;)..

Answer (score 15):

The transformer should have a specification sheet that details such things are max. temperature.  Since this one is custom, it seems that you should have that available.

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted, it's a perfectly valid answer. There's no one-size-fits-all safe temperature, as what you measure on the outside is likely way below the temperature of the inner layers of the wiring. Only the designer of the transformer knows what temperature is the insulation rated for and how that translates to external/ambient temps.

Comment: re: why could the answer be downvoted: it reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: No, the above is an answer, this is more like a comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments"